# Water leak from busted hoae

Tags: hose

I need to drive one mile is it ok to drive car. When I pour water in and also add to reservoir the water leaks out immediately.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no. We would recommend that you don't drive that car at all. Get it towed and repaired.